# Secure hidden fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to check if an answer is correct:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","teachme");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT question, answer, explanation FROM grade8u1 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo ("<b>Question</b>: $row[0]<br>");
echo ("<b>Answer</b>: $row[1]<br>");
echo ("<b>Explanation</b>:<br> $row[2]<br>");

if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    $answer = $_POST['realanswer'];
    if ($_POST['answer'] == $answer) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Last answer was correct";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Last answer was incorrect";
    }
}
?>
<form action="random.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="realanswer" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
    Answer: <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There is a problem because anyone can check or edit the value of the hidden field. I tried other ways such as using sessions but they get replaced each time the user presses submit.
Thanks, Tom.

Comment: How did you try with a session?

Comment: maybe use an id for the question/answer and use that for hidden filed

Comment: people can edit the value of hidden input field with inspect element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. Use encryption. A (secret) server-side key means you can set the hidden input to an encrypted string which can only be decrypted by the server.
2. Use a session (better for security, although a nitpicker would point out that some super-strange people & browsers won't support it).

If sessions didn't work for you before, you didn't use them correctly! (probably a forgotten `session_start()` call; that's what it usually is)

Also if this is for a CAPTCHA or similar then don't go with option (1); hackers could re-use the same hidden-answer/real-answer combination many times. You could reduce the problem by adding & checking timestamps or making the values single-use, but it would be much easier to use sessions.

Comment: when the user presses the button, $_SESSION is given the new answer, not the previous one. I need the previous answer.

Comment: @Tom then it sounds as though you replaced it with the new question before checking the old one. Do that the other way around or store the old value in a temporary.

Comment: I also cant use encryption, people can simply edit the value of the hidden field using chrome, safari, etc.

Comment: @Tom yes, but they will only be able to do so successfully if they already have a "good" pair (see my note at the bottom) or manage to figure out the key. Sessions are the better option though.

Comment: A hidden-value/real-value pair which they know works. Like if my encryption was to shift every character by 1 then a good pair would be `ifmmp` and `hello` (of course you would use a real encryption function!). The user would see `ifmmp` if they looked behind the scenes, but if we assume a good encryption, it leaves them none-the-wiser on what to write. But if they already know `ifmmp` matches `hello`, they can send that for every question and get them "right".

Comment: As you are `posting` the answers. Why don't you scrap the idea of the hidden input and load the contents as a PHP Variable? then work with that

Comment: @DarylGill I believe he is using a SESSION again now. The hidden input is more a theoretical discussion, which isn't the best option here.

Comment: @Dave I understand what the OP is doing, but 9/10 times Idon't use a hidden field for form processing. I can use create the information server sided and will use it server sided.. Because 9 time out of 10 the point of a hidden field is not to be maniuplated client-sided

Comment: What do you mean by load the contents as a PHP variable? Using sessions?